# Merge stored procedure and CTE(function) together to get results from reference table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Situation**

I'm working on a project where my GPS sends latitude and longitude to a SQL Server database. This all works fine. Then I have a report that calls a stored procedure that returns latitude/longitude and other information.

Then using any of my latitude and longitude, I have a CTE that returns the nearest city based on the latitude/longitude.

**Difficulty**

The difficulty that I am experiencing right now, is that I am stomped for a way to tie in those two queries in such a way that when I'm running my report the name of my city is retrieved as well.

As mentioned the stored procedure returns the Lat/lng and the CTE (maybe it should be a function ) gets me the name from the Lat/lng (right now it's hard coded).

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovementRepP]
    @GPSID nvarchar(50),
    @rSdate date,
    @rEdate date 
AS
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 120), 1, 10) as RecordDate,
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 114), 0, 13) as RecordTime,
        Latitude, Longitude, DeviceId,
        * 
    FROM 
        locationhistory A
    INNER JOIN 
        devices B ON A.DeviceId = B.id
    WHERE
        DeviceName = @GPSID
        AND SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(8), CreateTime, 112), 1, 10) BETWEEN @rSdate AND @rEdate
```

CTE that gets me cityname/city ID based on the lat/long it's supplied:

```
;WITH Distance_CTE ([geonameid], distance) AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT 
        [geonameid], 
        (3959 * acos(cos(radians(15.312015)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-61.388295)) + sin(radians(15.312015)) * sin(radians(latitude )))) AS distance 
    FROM 
        [GeoNames] 
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT TOP 1 [geonameid], distance
FROM Distance_CTE
WHERE DISTANCE < 20
ORDER BY DISTANCE
```

**EDIT**

Results from the stored procedure:

```
ID  Deviceid     Latitude    Longitude   Speed  Dir     CreateTime
505     4       15.31156    -61.3880467 6.52    0   2016-12-19 11:41:59.000
506     4       15.3175567  -61.39057   32.47   0   2016-12-19 11:43:00.000
507     4       15.32653    -61.39533   36.91   0   2016-12-19 11:44:01.000
508     4       15.330445   -61.3912917 13.45   0   2016-12-19 11:45:01.000
509     4       15.334425   -61.39001   20.46   0   2016-12-19 11:46:02.000
510     4       15.334445   -61.389295  14.57   0   2016-12-19 11:47:05.000
```

Results from CTE

```
 geonameid  distance
 9063952    0.173565252078886
```

When I pass in a latitude/longitude to the CTE a geonameid is returned. 
What I am trying to do is, get this geonameid INTO my stored procedure.

Hope it's a bit clearer

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. These two queries seem to be totally unrelated to each other. You need to provide some details so people can help you.

Comment: @SeanLange edited it a bit. thnks

Comment: Nope they are completely disjointed queries. You have a cte that will always return the same value because there is no predicate other than distance. Are you not providing all the details there? Like you also have lat and long predicates in there? Assuming that is the case you could easily this to your procedure. But again you just haven't given us enough details here.

Comment: The latitude and longitude is a parameter that the CTE takes to work ( in this example it is hard coded in there). The procedure doesnt take lat/long as a parameter so it cant pass it to the CTE. 
I'm more less looking for a way to feed the cTE the lat/long to then return me the city id

Comment: I think you are confused about what a cte is and how they work. They are nothing like functions. They are just an inline view. You can't pass them values. From what you have posted there is absolutely nothing in common between the cte and procedure. Can you edit the procedure? Have it also return the data you want. It is really hard to help here because it isn't clear what you are trying to do and I can't see your screen.

Comment: @SeanLange I shouldnt say "pass to the CTE, you're right you cant pass anything to it, I was referring to placing it in a function. The second query didnt have to be a CTE, i just made it one because I was using a having on a column that didnt exist.
The store procedure returns the deviceID, latitude and longitude between a time frame.
The CTE/ second query has the ability to return the city name. 
I cant place the second query in the first because at run time it doesnt know the latitude/longitude...so how will i use it as parameter in the query to get the city name?

Comment: I give up. I have tried to get you to provide some information that would actually be useful. Seeing some sample data and table structures along with desired output would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134697/discussion-between-niana-and-sean-lange).

Comment: In your stored proc `WHERE` clause, do not convert your date to VARCHAR and then back to DATE (implicitly). Rather, say `WHERE CAST(CreateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN @rSdate AND @rEdate`. This way, the query optimizer will be able to use an index on the `CreateDate` column (if any); you will have cleaner code and better performance.

Comment: @Serge Thanks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this (update: confirmed to work after removing a semi-colon from function), but I believe it will do what you need -- possibly too slowly though.
You may need to fix the parameter types, and just the cross apply line has been added to your stored proc.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCity]
(

@Latitude decimal(9,6), @Longitude decimal(9,6) 
)    
RETURNS TABLE
AS  

RETURN

WITH Distance_CTE ([geonameid], distance)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
SELECT [geonameid], (3959 * acos(cos(radians(@Latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(@Longitude)) + sin(radians(@Latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude )))) AS distance 
FROM [GeoNames] 
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT top 1 [geonameid], distance
FROM Distance_CTE
WHERE DISTANCE < 20
order by DISTANCE
```

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovementRepP]
@GPSID nvarchar(50),
@rSdate date,
@rEdate date 
AS
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 120),1,10) as RecordDate,
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 114),0,13) as RecordTime,Latitude,Longitude,DeviceId,
* FROM locationhistory A
INNER JOIN devices B 
ON A.DeviceId=B.id
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetCity(Latitude, Longitude)
WHERE
DeviceName=@GPSID
AND
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(8), CreateTime, 112),1,10)
BETWEEN @rSdate AND @rEdate
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use CROSS APPLY to get the nearest city. An example would look like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 120),1,10) as RecordDate,
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), CreateTime, 114),0,13) as RecordTime,Latitude,Longitude,DeviceId,
* FROM locationhistory A
cross apply
(
  SELECT top 1 [geonameid], (3959 * acos(cos(radians(A.Latitude)) * cos(radians(g.latitude)) * cos(radians(g.longitude) - radians(A.Longitude)) + sin(radians(A.Latitude)) * sin(radians(g.latitude )))) AS distance 
  FROM [GeoNames] g
  ORDER BY distance 
) nearest
INNER JOIN devices B 
ON A.DeviceId=B.id
WHERE
DeviceName=@GPSID
AND
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(8), CreateTime, 112),1,10)
BETWEEN @rSdate AND @rEdate
```

Default disclaimer, code is untested, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server built-in geography::[Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx) and [STDistance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) methods:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovementRepP] @GPSID  NVARCHAR(50),
                                         @rSdate DATE,
                                         @rEdate DATE
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT( VARCHAR(12), CreateTime, 120), 1, 10) AS RecordDate,
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT( VARCHAR(12), CreateTime, 114), 0, 13) AS RecordTime,
            Latitude,
            Longitude,
            DeviceId,
            g.geonameid,
          geography::Point(g.latitude, g.longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(A.latitude, A.longitude)) AS Distance
     FROM locationhistory A
          INNER JOIN devices B ON A.DeviceId = B.id
        INNER JOIN [GeoNames] g
          ON geography::Point(g.latitude, g.longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(A.latitude, A.longitude)) < 20
     WHERE DeviceName = @GPSID
           AND SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CreateTime, 112), 1, 10) BETWEEN @rSdate AND @rEdate;

END
```

Comment: have tried your answer but, it comes up blank and results are returned when I comment out the geoNames table. 
Also I got an error cause Point needs three parameters and i used,4326 as the last one, let me know if that was correct to do